# Product flavor in Xamrin.Android

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.android, android-productflavors

I am working on Xamrin android project. I required to add multiple build variant & product flavour for different clients. In a native Android application, we can manage it with [Build variant](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/build-variants) and [Product flavour](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide#TOC-Product-flavors).

I need to the changes Splash screen, app_icon, package name & theme for different product flavour.

I did not get any official document which explains this feature.

any help appreciated.

Comment: We don't have Gradle with Xamarin projects. You will need to handle this yourself in a build script or csproj configuration.

Comment: can you please share something for reference?

Comment: You could use the choose element in your csproj file: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/choose-element-msbuild?view=vs-2017

Comment: is this possible to change resources using this?  i am checking this @Cheesebaron . Thanks

Comment: Whoever flag for closed, please comment your reason. I have posted question with very specific issue & limitation in Xamrin.

Comment: Don't use the android tag next time. They don't understand xamarin.

Comment: @Cheesebaron updated tags. I have android tag here because i need to implement same like native android product flavor & build variant.